# how to maintain the state and pass data between.multiple activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I am developing airport transfer app. I have 4 step to complete order.
Step 1 - need to collect users arrival info

Step 2 - choose car base on the data of first step

Step 3 - collect personal info

Step 4 - payment

So my question is what approach is the best to pass data and maintain the data if user back to previous step. Should i use activities or fragment?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether you use activity or fragment. You can use a global stack to store the use data and status, when going step furthur, you can push user data into stack and when going back to previous step, you can pop the top data of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

In my words,I will use fragments in an activity.

Firstly,I will definite a variable whose  class implements Parcelable or Serializable in an activity.Then I use this variable 
to pass the data and maintain the data.In addition,The way use stack is a good idea.